# dynamic table sort of like a view, but with an updatable extra column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a two tables people and checklists. Checklists are things that all people will have to do and the list may change from time to time.

I'm looking to create a third table that keeps track of whether each person has completed a checklist item. But I don't want to have to go through an manually add a new row to the third table every time a new checklist item is added to the checklist table. I don't want to have to remove an entry from this table every time a checklist item is deleted. Is there a way to make my database server do this for me?

Comment: Make a trigger and let server do it for you

Comment: Add a foreign key constraint - now you can't delete a checklist item without removing the tracker entries.  Make it so if there isn't a row in the tracker table then this means that the task hasn't been completed yet - now you don't have to worry about populating this table either?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want a third table?  Just update the checklist table with the completion date when it was completed.

You can create a view on the `checklistitems` table, so you can see only open items or only completed items.

Moving items between tables is a bad idea.  You are much better off just using flags to keep track of what is and isn't in a particular state.  An `update` on a single row is relatively fast.  A `delete` followed by an `insert` on a another table is much slower.

Comment: Each person has to complete each checklist item. That is, there's not one item to be finished by any person. Each person has to check off each item.

Comment: @TomJ . . . So?  Why does that require another table?